# Calculate the std dev in python

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, data-analysis

I have the following list:
`daily_climb = [30, 21, 33, 77, 44, 45, 23, 45, 12, 34, 55]` 
Which represents in cm the daily climb of a snail.
The snail reaches the top of the well at 125cm

Every night, the snail slides down 20cm

What is the standard deviation of its displacement considering ONLY those full days in which the Snaill was climbing? ( Because at some days the snail ends up lower than he started)

Therefore, I 1st calculate a list were the snail actually, displaced positively:

```
displacement = []
advance_cm = [30, 21, 33, 77, 44, 45, 23, 45, 12, 34, 55]
nightly_distance = -20

for i in advance_cm:
    net_distance = i + nightly_distance
    if net_distance > 0:
        displacement.append(net_distance)

print(displacement)
```

Which results in the list:
`displacement = [10, 1, 13, 57, 24, 25, 3, 25, 14, 35]`

Now we can calculate the std deviation:

```
# Standard deviation of displacement during the day
def standard_deviation():
    displacement_list = [10, 1, 13, 57, 24, 25, 3, 25, 14, 35]
    std_dev = np.std(displacement_list, ddof=0)  # Use ddof=0 for population standard deviation
    return round(std_dev, 2)

solution5 = standard_deviation()
print(solution5)
```

The output is: `15.78`

Desired output: `19.44`

My solution is incorrect! Even when changing from population to sample.

Comment: I don't understand what I'm doing wrong!  Maybe the list I'm using is not correct?

Comment: Is `displacement` correct? And how did you compute `19.44`?

Comment: Are you accounting for the final day when the snail makes it out of the well without falling back. Should the final element by 55 instead of 35?

Comment: I googled the question and you might have missed a piece of information. The snail escapes a well, if it surpassed at a given day 125 cm. If you consider that, you will get 19.44 ( `np.cumsum` might become handy for that).

Comment: @Flow sorry for missing that...

Comment: @Flow can you send me a USDT BEP20 addy?

Answer (score 1):

The calculations I did were in fact correct.
The issue lays in the list.

I made this list with a for loop and subtracting the nightly_fall = -20 and > 0 to make sure that day the snail actually displaced, resulting in:

```
displacement = [10, 1, 13, 57, 24, 25, 3, 25, 14, 35]
```

That is why

```
len(daily_climb) = 11
len(displacement_list) = 10
```

The day 9 it climbs 12, resulting in a net loss of 8cm in that day.

The question was:

> What is the standard deviation of its displacement considering ONLY
> those full days in which the Snail was climbing?

That is why I assumed this list was correct, but the thing is on day 5, the snail reaches 125cm of height accounting for the nightly fall and iterating through the daily_climb list.

```
def escape():
    daily_climb = [30, 21, 33, 77, 44, 45, 23, 45, 12, 34, 55]
    wall_height = 125
    total_distance_climbed = 0
    days = 0

    while total_distance_climbed < wall_height:
        total_distance_climbed += daily_climb[days] - 20  # Subtract 20 cm for each night
        if total_distance_climbed >= wall_height:
            break
        days += 1

    return days

solution1 = escape()
print(solution1)
```

Therefore, the list I should have used was the displacement_list but only
counting up to the 5th day:

```
displacement = [10, 1, 13, 57, 24, 25, 3, 25, 14, 35]
correct_list = [10, 1, 13, 57, 24] #THE SNAIL REACHES THE TOP
```

Sorry for not including originally the info about the snail reaching the top of the well at 125cm, but the way the question was **"ONLY those full days in which the Snaill was climbing?"** made me think to include the full displacemetn_list

Comment: Hmm, where do the remaining climb values come from then? Did the snail climb *into the air*?

Comment: Good thought! Thats what made me think I should use the displacement list!

Answer (score 0):

First to calculate the standard deviation you don't need to remove 20 to each displacement ! V(X+a)=V(X)

But even manually we don't find the right stddev (we find 12.560254774486065)

```
import numpy as np

L=[10, 1, 13, 57, 24, 25, 3, 25, 14, 35]

filtered_L = [x for x in L if abs(x) >= 20]

s=0

for e in filtered_L:
    s+=e

mean=s/len(filtered_L)

sum_square=0

for k in filtered_L:
    sum_square+=(k-mean)**2

print(np.sqrt(sum_square/(len(filtered_L))))
print(np.std(filtered_L))
```

Comment: Yes, you do! Remember the question? "What is the standard deviation of its displacement considering ONLY those full days in which the Snaill was climbing? ( Because on some days the snail ends up lower than he started)" Maybe remove day 9 which results in -8 and calculate on original list?

Comment: @Capybara69 But you can take the climb values >20, without subtracting 20. No?

Comment: Yes you're right, but even without them it doesn't work :/

Comment: It does not... thats the issue! I think the displacement_list is correct, but the std dev does not match expected 19.44 result!

Comment: The issue is his value of 19.44, it might be wrong

Comment: The issue is that he didn't give either the correct question or the complete question!

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear! You didn't give the whole question! (As @flow correctly pointed out).

You also misinterpreted the statement "considering ONLY those full days in which the Snail was climbing?" and FAILED TO GIVE THE HEIGHT 125 cm (OF THE WELL THAT YOU FAILED TO TELL US THAT THE SNAIL WAS IN!). - **until your recent edit!**

Here's the solution in Fortran - you can convert it to Python.

```
program quick
   implicit none
   real, allocatable :: A(:)
   integer N

   A = [30, 21, 33,  77,  44,  45,  23,  45,  12,  34, 55]

   A = A - 20
   N = 1;
   do while ( sum( A(1:N+1) ) < 125 )       ! WHOLE days the snail climbs out of a 125 cm well
      N = N + 1
   end do
   A = A(1:N)                               ! N is 5, A is [10, 1, 13, 57, 24]

   print *, sqrt( ( sum( A * A ) / N - ( sum( A ) / N ) ** 2 ) )

end program quick
```

Output:

```
   19.4422226
```